# Setting response code in Servlet Filter

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, filter

I have a class which implements `javax.servlet.Filter` which does some authentication on a token object set in the session, if the token becomes invalid I wish to return a 403 forbidden response. So I have something like

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throw ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    ...
    ...
    // Something has gone wrong with auth set the response code and
    // continue with the chain
    response.setStatus(403);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

What I want then to happen is for the `<error-page>` defined in the web.xml to trigger against the 403 response code

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/forbidden.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

I can see that the network tab of the browser dev tools correctly shows a 403 type response. But the browser doesn't redirect to the error page like I'm expecting, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My mistake was doing `response.setStatus(403)` what needed to happen was

```
response.sendError(403);
return;
```

Comment: This worked very well for me, I am using custom error message to send a response back to UI.
     
catch (Exception e) {
     log.error(String.format("Exception occured in token validation : %s", e.getMessage()));
 ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(401, AuthzError.INVALIDAUTHTOKEN.getDescription());
 return;
}     

    }

Comment: How do I change the timestamp formatting in the response?